# Recent Files List in c# Windows forms .net 4

Tags: c#, winforms

Just wondering if somebody has implemented a Recent Files list and how they have approached.
Looking for ideas.

Was thinking of a collection and saving as xml file somewhere(Users....)
and when a new file is added check if exists and if does remove and re-add so that you always have the latest 20 files for example.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The feature is called MRU (Most Recently Used). You can find a nice implementation on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mrutoolstripmenu.aspx

Comment: Using file and instead of registry makes things portable and interchangeable. But in this case, it looks ok because it's machine specific.

Comment: Look like this implement use Registry Key to save recent path (If I understand the source code correctly) which I strongly against. I don't want any of my software to mess around my Window Registry.